# How to draw scatter plot from vector attribute table or vector (point) layer in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, vector, attribute-table, scatterplot

I have a vector layer (point) with attribute columns **cat, value1 and value2**. I need to draw a scatter plot (value1 vs value2) in GRASS.

I can see scatter plot option for raster maps in GRASS? Is there a option available for vector/point map in GRASS?

Comment: I've solved the problem (scatter plot from vector attribute table)  by importing attribute table in R (within GRASS) and installed "rgrass7" library. However, I'm looking for a command in GRASS to draw a scatter plot from vector (point) attribute table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completness also here:
I am not aware of a GUI tool for that, sorry. But you have the full power of [R](https://cran.r-project.org/) at your fingertips:

In your GRASS console start `R` and then

```
# Load GRASS library
library("rgrass7")

# Fetch attributes
attributes <- execGRASS("v.db.select", map=’yourvectormap’, separator=’,’)

# Parse the result
con <- textConnection(attributes)
data <- read.csv(con, header=TRUE)
str(data)

#Make your plot
plot(value1 ~ value2, data=data)
```

See also the [GRASS-R-Wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics/rgrass7) and an [introduction into scatterplots in R](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html).